# Where are rsa_pub_enc and rsa_priv_dec in the OpenSSL source?

Tags: openssl, rsa

I was going through the source code of openSSL trying to figure out how RSA is implemented in openSSL. I went through the documentation and found out that the functions RSA_public_encrypt and RSA_private_decrypt do the tasks.

However, these functions point to rsa_pub_enc , rsa_priv_dec respectively which I can't find anywhere. Any headstart on how to read the openSSL cource code would be very helpful.

P.S. I am using openssl-1.0.2d.tar.gz tarball.

Answer (score 1):

I just discover your post today while having strictly same question with some time spent to find the answer (grep on "rsa_pub_enc" sequence).

Finally I understood in analyzing the main file (rsa_test.c) and then RSA_new() function, that when the openssl default RSA method is used (i.e. RSA_PKCS1_SSLeay method), the RSA_METHOD structure points to the "RSA_eay_public_encrypt()" function within rsa_eay.c file (replacing the generic rsa_pub_enc function as defined in rsa.h file for RSA_METHOD structure).

So openssl source code for RSA encryption / decryption implementation is available from rsa_eay.c file, when default method is used.
Of course this also applies to other rsa encrypt/decrypt functions with public or private key.